# how to select query from drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-database

i have this query on drupal 6

```
$catq=' ( SELECT term_node.nid as node_id FROM {term_node} WHERE tid='.$catint.') as cat, '
```

i have upgrade it like this

```
$query=db_select('term_node');
                    ->addfield('term_node', 'nid', 'node');
                    ->field('term_node', 'node' ); 
                    ->condition('term_node.tid', = , $catint);
                $cat=$query->addfield($query, 'cat');
```

is it wrong?

Comment: Why dont you run it and find out?

Comment: sorry, but I can not run it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.
The right syntax for query - keeping your data will be:

```
$query = db_select('term_node', 't')
            ->fields('t')
            ->condition('term_node.tid', $catint, '=')
            ->execute();
          $logo = $query->fetchAll();
```

But in drupal 7 there is no table term_node, probably you  need 'taxonomy_index'.

Comment: But with field('t') i do a select of all field of the table, i need only term_node.nid, and for set the aliases of the all query?
I have this table because we have develop a new database =)
P.S. thanks for help! =)

Comment: P.P.S. is recursive, i recall $catq in another query in the file